# How to prepare/bundle a swift + react native project for release

Tags: swift, react-native

I'm trying to create a main.jsbundle and prepare my swift app for device testing and app store release. The RN docs speak to doing so via objective-c but not swift.

I'm attempting to do this inside `appdelegate.swift` for a pre-existing swift codebase (have localhost working fine) but can't seem to translate  `jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];` into something that will satisfy the complier.

Here's what I've tried:
- `let jsCodeLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle()(URLForResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")`

- error: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSBundle'`

Comment: thanks @deanware that works

Comment: If you found the information I provided useful then please accept my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Try `let jsCodeLocation = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("main", withExtension: "jsbundle")`

Answer (score 2):

For the latest versions of xcode/swift, I got it working with:

```
jsCodeLocation = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")!
```

Answer (score 0):

I got mine going with

```
 let jsCodeLocation: URL! =
 RCTBundleURLProvider.sharedSettings().jsBundleURL(
     forFallbackResource: "main", fallbackExtension: "jsbundle"
 )
```